# ArcGIS Server Manager (10.2.2) - permissions applied to folder not "sticking"

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I was able to do this before updating to 10.2.2, because I have several other folders with specific permissions applied via local role store.  User store is Active Directory.  Data store is flat files via UNC to shared drive.

Each time I edit the permissions of a newly-created folder, I choose private, un-check allow access to all users, & add the role to allowed roles.  Saving says that, "permissions applied successfully," but the lock icon remains open, & checking the permissions shows that the folder is public.

I have tried deleting & re-creating the folder in the server manager.